# Oracle Privileges

Tags: oracle11g

What kind of privilege do I need to truncate a table on any Oracle database? Do I need a delete any table privilege or drop any table privilege?

Truncating a table, deletes the rows from the table. But the table structure remains the same. So a delete privilege is enough to truncate a table? Is that correct?

[This website](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/statements_10007.htm#CHDDGIHF) shows a drop any table privilege is required. But some books that I referred showed delete is enough. Please clarify

Comment: Well, try it out and see.

Answer (score 0):

To delete a Table Exactly Drop command will be used.If you Truncate the table ,Structure will be Present and Appears when you enter DESC command.Even though both gives same result but TRUNCATE is faster and doesn't use as much undo option as  DELETE.So No chance of Rollback and commit cmds after truncate.To truncate a table or cluster,you must have DROP ANY TABLE system privilege.Truncate option having no privileges to Normal user,it's a dba cmd. Becose it cant rollback and powerful option. So You should connect sys/manager and enter "conn sys as sysdba".Grant commnd is used to give Access to work for Normal user.Try It.

Comment: I tried it as a DBA user. It is requiring a Drop any table privilege. Appreciate your suggestion.